# MySQL Entity Framework Wraps query into sub-select for Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We support both MSSQL and MySQL for Entityframework 6 in an MVC 5 Application. Now, the problem I am having is when using the MySQL connectors and LINQ, queries which have an INNER JOIN and an ORDER BY will cause the query to be brought into a sub-select and the ORDER BY is applied on the outside. This causes a substantial performance impact. This does not happen when using the MSSQL connector. Here is an example:

```
SELECT 
    `Project3`.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `Extent1`.*,
            `Extent2`.`Name_First`
    FROM
        `ResultRecord` AS `Extent1`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `ResultInputEntity` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`Id` = `Extent2`.`Id`
    WHERE
        `Extent1`.`DateCreated` <= '4/4/2016 6:29:59 PM'
            AND `Extent1`.`DateCreated` >= '12/31/2015 6:30:00 PM'
            AND 0000 = `Extent1`.`CustomerId`
            AND (`Extent1`.`InUseById` IS NULL OR 0000 = `Extent1`.`InUseById` OR `Extent1`.`LockExpiration` < '4/4/2016 6:29:59 PM')
            AND `Extent1`.`DivisionId` IN (0000)
            AND `Extent1`.`IsDeleted` != 1
            AND EXISTS( SELECT 
                1 AS `C1`
            FROM
                `ResultInputEntityIdentification` AS `Extent3`
            WHERE
                `Extent1`.`Id` = `Extent3`.`InputEntity_Id`
                    AND 0 = `Extent3`.`Type`
                    AND '0000' = `Extent3`.`Number`
                    AND NOT (`Extent3`.`Number` IS NULL)
                    OR LENGTH(`Extent3`.`Number`) = 0)
            AND EXISTS( SELECT 
                1 AS `C1`
            FROM
                `ResultRecordAssignment` AS `Extent4`
            WHERE
                1 = `Extent4`.`AssignmentType`
                    AND `Extent4`.`AssignmentId` = 0000
                    OR 2 = `Extent4`.`AssignmentType`
                    AND `Extent4`.`AssignmentId` = 0000
                    AND `Extent4`.`ResultRecordId` = `Extent1`.`Id`)) AS `Project3`
ORDER BY `Project3`.`DateCreated` ASC , `Project3`.`Name_First` ASC , `Project3`.`Id` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

This query simply times out when being ran against against a few million rows. This is the explain for the above query:

```
    | id | select_type        | table   | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                        | key                        | key_len | ref        | rows     | extra                                        |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | Extent1 | ref  | IX_ResultRecord_CustomerId,IX_ResultRecord_DateCreated,IX_ResultRecord_IsDeleted,IX_ResultRecord_InUseById,IX_ResultRecord_LockExpiration,IX_ResultRecord_DivisionId | IX_ResultRecord_CustomerId | 4       | const      | 1        | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | Extent2 | ref  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                              | PRIMARY                    | 8       | Extent1.Id | 1        |                                              |
    |  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Extent4 | ref  | IX_RA_AT,IX_RA_A_ID,IX_RA_RR_ID                                                                                                                                      | IX_RA_A_ID                 | 5       | const      | 1        | Using where                                  |
    |  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Extent3 | ALL  | IX_InputEntity_Id,IX_InputEntityIdentification_Type,IX_InputEntityIdentification_Number                                                                              |                            |         |            | 14341877 | Using where
```

Now, as it would get generated in MSSQL, or we simply get rid of the sub select to ORDER BY, the improvement is dramatic!

```
SELECT 
    `Extent1`.*, 
    `Extent2`.`Name_First`
FROM
    `ResultRecord` AS `Extent1`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `ResultInputEntity` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`Id` = `Extent2`.`Id`
WHERE
    `Extent1`.`DateCreated` <= '4/4/2016 6:29:59 PM'
        AND `Extent1`.`DateCreated` >= '12/31/2015 6:30:00 PM'
        AND 0000 = `Extent1`.`CustomerId`
        AND (`Extent1`.`InUseById` IS NULL
        OR 0000 = `Extent1`.`InUseById`
        OR `Extent1`.`LockExpiration` < '4/4/2016 6:29:59 PM')
        AND `Extent1`.`DivisionId` IN (0000)
        AND `Extent1`.`IsDeleted` != 1
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            1 AS `C1`
        FROM
            `ResultInputEntityIdentification` AS `Extent3`
        WHERE
            `Extent1`.`Id` = `Extent3`.`InputEntity_Id`
                AND 9 = `Extent3`.`Type`
                AND '0000' = `Extent3`.`Number`
                AND NOT (`Extent3`.`Number` IS NULL)
                OR LENGTH(`Extent3`.`Number`) = 0)
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            1 AS `C1`
        FROM
            `ResultRecordAssignment` AS `Extent4`
        WHERE
            1 = `Extent4`.`AssignmentType`
                AND `Extent4`.`AssignmentId` = 0000
                OR 2 = `Extent4`.`AssignmentType`
                AND `Extent4`.`AssignmentId` = 0000
                AND `Extent4`.`ResultRecordId` = `Extent1`.`Id`)
ORDER BY `Extent1`.`DateCreated` ASC , `Extent2`.`Name_First` ASC , `Extent1`.`Id` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

This query now runs in 0.10 seconds! And the explain plan is now this:

```
| id | select_type  | table       | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                | key                               | key_len | ref                    | rows | extra                                       |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | ALL  | distinct_key                                                                                                                                                                 |                                   |         |                        | 1    | Using temporary; Using filesort             |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | Extent1     | ref  | PRIMARY,IX_ResultRecord_CustomerId,IX_ResultRecord_DateCreated,IX_ResultRecord_IsDeleted,IX_ResultRecord_InUseById,IX_ResultRecord_LockExpiration,IX_ResultRecord_DivisionId | PRIMARY                           | 8       | Extent3.InputEntity_Id | 1    | Using where                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | Extent4     | ref  | IX_RA_AT,IX_RA_A_ID,IX_RA_RR_ID                                                                                                                                              | IX_RA_RR_ID                       | 8       | Extent3.InputEntity_Id | 1    | Using where; Start temporary; End temporary |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | Extent2     | ref  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                           | 8       | Extent3.InputEntity_Id | 1    |                                             |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | Extent3     | ref  | IX_InputEntity_Id,IX_InputEntityIdentification_Type,IX_InputEntityIdentification_Number                                                                                      | IX_InputEntityIdentification_Type | 4       | const                  | 1    | Using where                                 |
```

Now, I have had this issue many times across the system, and it is clear that it is an issue with the MySQL EF 6 Connector deciding to always wrap queries in a sub-select to apply the ORDER BY, but only when there is a join in the query. This is causing major performance issues. Some answers I have seen suggest modifying the connector source code, but that can be tedious, has anyone had this same issue, know a work around, modified the connector already or have any other suggestions besides simply moving to SQL Server and leaving MySQL behind, as that is not an option.

Comment: Not a nice option, but it looks like you should do the ordering in memory. And file a firm feature request at MySQL Connector.

Comment: That is problematic mainly because of the amount of data these requests can bring back. I will definitely be filing a feature request. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in order to work around this with the MySQL Driver, your entire lambda must be written in one go. Meaning in ONE Where(..) Predicate. This way the driver knows that it is all one result set. Now, if you build an initial IQueryable, and then keep appending Where clauses to it which access child tables, it will believe that there are multiple result sets and therefore wrap your entire query into a sub-select in order to sort and limit it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look to SQL Server generated SQL? Is it different or only performances are different?

Because [usually] is not the provider that decide the structure of the query (i.e. order a subquery). The provider just translate the structure of the query to the syntax of the DBMS. So, In your case the problem could be the DBMS optimizer.

In issues similar to your I used a different approach based on mapping a query to entities i.e. using `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery`.

Comment: I believe .ExecuteStoreQuery is just to run plain SQL queries which I write. We may have to move towards that, the issue is that these queries are dynamically built, therefore, it would be a big task to move away from LINQ at the moment.

Comment: With ExecuteStoreQuery you can run the query you need optimized (by you) for the store. Usually there are few queries that needs to be optimized for the DBMS (otherwise you need to change the ORM i.e. using Dapper). Massive upsert and delete is worst (a solution in SQL Server is to use bulk copy but with MySQL you can't use same libraries).  About SQL did you see if the query is nested in rhe same way?

Comment: Yes, dapper has been in discussion, the down side is that we would need a massive rewrite of functionality to move away from EF at the moment. And in SQL Server it does not get nested. The second query I posted in my question is the one generated by MSSQL. Thus, letting us know that the MySQL Connector for EF is the culprit.